Timing of backups from .bash_logout
If I run incremental backups with rsync from the .bash_logout files, when will the backup complete its work? Before logout or after?

~/.bash_logout is run just before logging out, as $USER.

Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423958/what-is-the-purpose-of-bash-logout I'm not sure if this is called when closing a terminal, the GUI session and/or the computer

If .bash_logout is only called once you close the session and shutdown the computer, it will probably stop the backup before it's finished. Did you try it?

@A.L opening a terminal will strt an interactive non-login shell, so no, closing a terminal doesn't source ~/.bash_logout. Only closing a login shell does that.

@terdon Thanks, this is also explained in the 2nd paragraph of this answer, cited in the link I shared before: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell

I know, @A.L,  but since your comment linking to that answer also said "I'm not sure if this is called when closing a terminal", I thought that wasn't clear and clarified.

The ~/.bash_logout script is sourced when you exit a login shell. If you are running a graphical system, then depending on your login manager, you might be starting a new login shell when you log in, in which case, you will run the commands in ~/.bash_logout when you log out.
If you have long running commands there, that will cause everything to wait until they have finished. I tested this by simply adding sleep 30 to my ~/.bash_logout, then starting a login shell with bash -l and exiting it with exit. The shell waited 30 seconds before closing.
So yes, you could add your backup options there, just test it first to be sure that your system does actually look at ~/.bash_logout when logging out. Assuming it does, then the system should start the backup process when you log out and then wait for your backup to finish before fully logging our or shutting down.

Thanks for the hints. I tried to edit bash_logout but didn't have permissions to change it. I will study further and see if I can change that

@Fibonacci that is worrying. That file should belong to your user. In fact, everything under your home directory should belong to your user, with very few, rare exceptions for specific setups.
